# Spring Data MongoDB aggregation - match by calculated value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, spring-data-mongodb

I've got a collection of documents with 2 Number fields and I need to filter all the documents based on a calculated condition:

```
Number1/Number2 >= CONST%
```

How can I make this posible using Spring Data Mongo and Aggregation?

## --UPDATE--

I've tried the following code:

```
return new RedactAggregationOperation(
            new BasicDBObject(
                    "$redact",
                    new BasicDBObject(
                            "$cond", new BasicDBObject()
                            .append("if", new BasicDBObject(
                                    "$gte", Arrays.asList(new BasicDBObject(
                                    "$divide",
                                    Arrays.asList(
                                            "$Number1",
                                            new BasicDBObject(
                                                    "$cond",
                                                    new BasicDBObject()
                                                            .append("$or", Arrays.asList(
                                                                    new BasicDBObject(
                                                                            "$eq", new BasicDBObject(
                                                                            "$Number2", 0)),
                                                                    new BasicDBObject(
                                                                            "$eq", new BasicDBObject(
                                                                            new BasicDBObject(
                                                                                    "$ifNull",
                                                                                    new BasicDBObject(
                                                                                            "$Number2", 0)).toString(), 0))))
                                                            .append("then", 1000000)
                                                            .append("else", "$Number2")), CONSTANT_VAR))
                            )))
                            .append("then", "$$KEEP")
                            .append("else", "$$PRUNE")
                    )
            )
    );
```

But there is an error "Unrecognized parameter to $cond: $or"
Could you please assist with this issue?

Comment: `"$cond"` should be an array, instead of `"$cond", new BasicDBObject()
                                                            .append("$or", Arrays.asList(`, replace that line with `"$cond", Arrays.asList( new BasicDBObject()
                                                            .append("$or", Arrays.asList(`

Comment: @chridam i guess there are also few issues with "$eq" operators.

Comment: Yes, and that as well. Where there is an array structure, you need to use the appropriate data structure, i.e. instead of `new BasicDBObject()` for arrays, wrap the data with `Arrays.asList()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is the **[`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** operator in the aggregation framework which allows you to proccess the above logical condition with the **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** operator and uses the special operations **[`$$KEEP`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#keep)** to "keep" the document where the logical condition is true or **[`$$PRUNE`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/#prune)** to "remove" the document where the condition was false.

This operation is similar to having a **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline that selects the fields in the collection and creates a new field that holds the result from the logical condition query and then a subsequent **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, except that **[`$redact`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** uses a single pipeline stage which is more efficient.

Consider the following example which demonstrate the above concept:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$gte": [
                        { "$divide": ["$Number1", "$Number2"] },
                        CONSTANT_VAR
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

---

Since there's [no support for the **`$redact`** operator yet](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-931) (at the time of writing), a workaround will be to implement an `AggregationOperation` interface that wraps the aggregation operation with a class to take in a `DBObject`:

```
public class RedactAggregationOperation implements AggregationOperation {
    private DBObject operation;

    public RedactAggregationOperation (DBObject operation) {
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    @Override
    public DBObject toDBObject(AggregationOperationContext context) {
        return context.getMappedObject(operation);
    }
}
```

which you can then use in `TypeAggregation`:

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    new RedactAggregationOperation(
        new BasicDBObject(
            "$redact",
            new BasicDBObject(
                "$cond", new BasicDBObject()
                    .append("if", new BasicDBObject(
                        "$gte", Arrays.asList(
                            new BasicDBObject(
                                "$divide", Arrays.asList( "$Number1", "$Number2" )
                            ), 
                            CONSTANT_VAR
                        )
                    )
                )
                .append("then", "$$KEEP")
                .append("else", "$$PRUNE")
            )
        )
    )
);

AggregationResults<Example> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
    (TypedAggregation<Example>) agg, Example.class);
```

---

**--UPDATE--**

Follow-up from the comments, to check for nulls or zero values on the `Number2` field in the division, you would have to nest a **[`$cond`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/)** expression with the logic instead.

The following example assumes you have a placeholder value of 1 if either `Number2` does not exist/is null or have a value of zero:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                { 
                    "$gte": [
                        { 
                            "$divide": [
                                "$Number1", {
                                    "$cond": [
                                        {
                                            "$or": [
                                                { "$eq": ["$Number2", 0] },
                                                { 
                                                    "$eq": [
                                                        { "$ifNull": ["$Number2", 0] }, 0
                                                    ]
                                                }
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        1,  // placeholder value if Number2 is 0
                                        "$Number2"                                          
                                    ]
                                }
                            ] 
                        },
                        CONSTANT_VAR
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

**Equivalent Spring Data Aggregation (untested)**

```
Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    new RedactAggregationOperation(
        new BasicDBObject(
            "$redact",
            new BasicDBObject(
                "$cond", Arrays.asList(
                    new BasicDBObject(
                        "$gte", Arrays.asList(
                            new BasicDBObject(
                                "$divide", Arrays.asList( 
                                    "$Number1", 
                                    new BasicDBObject(
                                        "$cond", Arrays.asList( 
                                            new BasicDBObject( "$or": Arrays.asList( 
                                                    new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.asList("$Number2", 0)),
                                                    new BasicDBObject("$eq", Arrays.asList(
                                                            new BasicDBObject("$ifNull", Arrays.asList("$Number2", 0)), 0
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            ),
                                            1,  // placeholder value if Number2 is 0
                                            "$Number2"                                          
                                        )
                                    ) 
                                )
                            ), 
                            CONSTANT_VAR
                        )
                    ), "$$KEEP", "$$PRUNE"
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Is it also possible to check if Number2 is not null (to prevent dividing by zero errors)?

Comment: Good call, you would need to put another `$cond` expression that does the checks instead. Do you intend to use a placeholder value if `Number2` is null or has a zero value?

Comment: could you please provide example in java. Keep getting error "Unrecognized parameter to $cond: $or"

Comment: Can you update your question with the code that's giving you the error, so that we can check where the bug is?