# How do you secure SpringBoot / Spring-Data Rest so user can only partially access to an object

Tags: java, spring-boot, rbac

I have an `spring boot` application using `spring-data-rest` that implement **role base access control** mechanism to secure access to resources base on user's roles.

The requirement is: user with a specific role can only access to some **parts of an object**.

For example: users with `staff` role can **only view/update** basic info (name, age) of object `user` but users with role `admin` can **do anything**

I'm now using `spring-security` with `pre/post` annotation to check again user's permissions but it only control accession to entire object.

Is there anyway do this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41609218/spring-data-mongodb-aggregation-match-by-calculated-value -> If you use mongodb, spring-data-mongodb has an option, but not sure `$redact` operator is yet supported in spring-data

Comment: You can use jCasbin: https://github.com/casbin/jcasbin

Answer (score 2):

The `@Secured`/`@RolesAllowed` annotation is used to specify a list of roles on a method. Hence, a user only can access that method if she has at least one of the specified roles.

You may have different methods to do specific task such as view/update/or something else. eg:

```java
@Secured({ "ROLE_VIEWER", "ROLE_EDITOR" }) //@RolesAllowed("ROLE_VIEWER")
public boolean isValidUsername(String username) {
    return userRoleRepository.isValidUsername(username);
}
```

Apart from that, a user's authority can also be checked programmatically, in raw java code, if the request object is available:
`request.isUserInRole("someAuthority")`, then perform the action or handle the error.

Answer (score 0):

You should custom rules. 
You need filter your resource by your self when accessing a resource collection.

You can throw an Exception in your controller or service when accessing a single resource. You can use `@ControllerAdvice` and `@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)` to catch your controller. Then return a 403 Error.
Such as

```
public class AccessErrorException extends Exception{

    public AccessErrorException(String message){
        super(message);
    }
}
```

The `ControlerAdvice`:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);

    @ExceptionHandler(AccessErrorException.class)
   public void handleException(AccessErrorException e){
        LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
        // do something send.error(403)
    }
}
```

The Service:

```
public interface RoleService {
   Role queryById() throw AccessErrorException;
}
```